# Go back to the First/Main activity without reloading it

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an android app. I need to call my MainActivity without reloading it as it has huge amount of data fetch from internet.

Suppose, I am on third activity now and I want to go back to MainActivity.

If I use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Third.this,Main.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

it will load MainActivity but I don't want to reload it. like from Second Activity I call `finish()` and it does exactly want i need.

Comment: are you loading data from the internet in your onResume() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

metntion it in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"

              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

do nothing inside the method `onResume()` and `onstart()` when coming back to this activity

and try `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` instead of `addFlags()` method

Answer (score 16):

This is how to do it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your manifest:

```
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

add this line to the activity in your manifest like this:

```
       <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Third activity when you want to go to first activity, put finish() mwthod there.

In Second activity, after onCreate() method, put 
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        finish();
    }

I think this code will work for you, jus try it.