# Android: navigate to first MainActivity in stack

Tags: android, navigation

By default Android creates new Activity instance and closes it, when user navigates back. That makes stack.

While trying with `launchMode`s different than `standard` we found that on some devices there is undesirable animation when launching those activities.

In our app there is a search, view by category, related and finally details,
that can bring user to thick stack.

**Is there simple way to add action "Return to home" that would discard all the stack down to MainActivity?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, launch a new Intent to your Home Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade);
finish();
```

With that flag you clean you stack and your HomeActivity it's now your main activity of your app.

Comment: Yes, but that would recreate the HomeActivity

Comment: If you need don't recreate the activity set it in the launch mode slingleTop|singleTask

Comment: > While trying with launchModes different than standard we found that on some devices there is undesirable animation when launching those activities.

Comment: The only to come to my mind it's try with override Pending Transition method, check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Found at [Go back to the First/Main activity without reloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042257/go-back-to-the-first-main-activity-without-reloading-it)

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

as from docs

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
>
> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

So without FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP it would cause the MainActivity to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, launch a new Intent to your Home Activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade)
finish();
```

With that flag you clean you stack and your HomeActivity it's now your main activity of your app.